# Prolog - Help understanding a rule

Tags: prolog, nodes

I've got a database full of facts such as:

```
checkpoint(checkpoint1,checkpoint2,2).
checkpoint(checkpoint2,checkpoint3,3).
checkpoint(checkpoint3,checkpoint4,4).
checkpoint(checkpoint4,checkpoint5,2).
checkpoint(checkpoint5,checkpoint6,2).
```

e.g checkpoint(firstcheckpoint,secondcheckpoint,timeinminutes).

Then the following rule tests if a journey is possible between two checkpoints in a race:

```
journey(X,Y):- checkpoint(X,_,_), checkpoint(_,Y,_),!; checkpoint(Y,_,_), checkpoint(_,X,_),!.

journey(X,Y):- checkpoint(X,Z,_), journey(Z,Y).
journey(X,Y):- checkpoint(Z2,Y,_), journey(X,Z2).
```

Note that you cant skip checkpoints, you can only get to checkpoint4 by first going to 1,2 then 3. You can however go backwards, such as going from checkpoint 4 back to 3.

I understand that this code checks if a journey is possible between two checkpoints if there is a intermediate checkpoint between X and Y, which in this case is Z. However I don't quite understand what Z2 is doing. I assume its just being used as another intermediate like Z, however why is it named as a different variable then? Can't Z2 just be changed to Z and it would still work?

Answer (score 1):

`Z2` can absolutely be renamed to `Z` in the last rule, and the logic of the rule will not change. The reason the author hesitated to use `Z` is probably because that variable does not denote a "midpoint" the way `Z` does in the first rule.

Personally, I would go with more descriptive variable names - `From` and `To` sound like good candidates:

```
journey(From,To):- checkpoint(From,Mid,_), journey(Mid,To).
journey(From,To):- checkpoint(Someplace,To,_), journey(From,Someplace).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename a variable without changing the meaning of a rule, if you rename **all** the occurrences the same way.

But the first journey rule looks wrong to me: what effect do you expect the cuts have there?
The disjunction has no chance to work, cause the first cut.

Leave just the first rule, then try `?- findall((X,Y),journey(X,Y),L).` 
You will see the only answer `L = [ (checkpoint1, checkpoint2)].`

So, the answer from @dasblinklight (+1) suggests a deeper correction apart variables renaming: just drop the first journey rule...

**EDIT**

This procedure (without cuts) extends the original specification, allowing to enumerate all possible journeys, and could match the original definition:

```
journey(X, Y):-
    journey([], X, Y).
journey(Visited, X, Y) :-
    ( checkpoint(X, I, _) ; checkpoint(I, X, _) ),
    \+ memberchk(I, Visited),
    ( I = Y ; journey([X|Visited], I, Y) ).
```

Comment: Hm well if I dont include the cuts at all I seem to fall into a infinite loop where after I get true, I can keep pressing ; and prolog will keep returning true. I sort of assumed after adding the cuts it just worked, but I'll try what you said in the comment.

Comment: After doing some tests it seems that the cuts are perfectly fine? I tested the original code by completly deleting the line after the disjunction and then tested a reverse journey to a checkpoint, which returned false as expected. However, with the disjunction and cuts if I test a reverse journey it returns true, suggesting it works perfectly fine?

Comment: You are right, deleting the first rule inhibits any solution. I will edit the answer...